How to clean a list in Excel?
I have following list in Excel in column A:

105)John/M Doe Q 1 +
106)Jane/M Doe M 1 +
107)Rahman/Mujib M 1 +
108)Rahman/MOHAMMAD AZAD J 0
109)Ahmed/Zafar T 1 +
110)Shah/Zaman L 1 +
111)RAHMAN/BHIMUL J 0
112)RASUL/SHEIK Z 1 +
113)RHAMAN/ZIAUR Q 1 +
114)RUHI/RAWZI ISLAM Q 0 +
115)SABUZ/RAQIB ISLAM R 2 +

My goal is to Remove all the data in bold and make a fresh list in column B

Is the data you want to remove truly formatted as BOLD? If so you will need VBA to do a character-by-character analysis. However, if the data you want to remove is because of it's position, you will need to include the logic that you use to decide which to remove as your information appears inconsistent.

Is there a way to find the position of space from the end of the cell i.e right to left?

Yes, using InStr, Mid or Right functions.

@Shahid Yes, there is. But your example doesn't show a consistent pattern. Some you split at the second and others at the third space from the end

You can extract one column (space as separator) by use of Python.
The very same is possible with Ribbon: Data > Text to columns
$ python -c <exampledata "import sys;print('\n'.join([ line.replace(')',' ').split(' ')[2] for line in sys.stdin]) )"
John/M
Jane/M
Rahman/Mujib
Rahman/MOHAMMAD
Ahmed/Zafar
Shah/Zaman
RAHMAN/BHIMUL
RASUL/SHEIK
RHAMAN/ZIAUR
RUHI/RAWZI
SABUZ/RAQIB

As your "field separator" is the SPACE character, you will always have problems with "fields" that have space(s) in them.
No automation or scripting can detect where to split such data perfectly.
*Note: [2] tells to pick out column 2.
.replace( '(' , ' ' ) replaces the parenthese with a space to make the line split there too.
Replace '\n' with '\t' to create a TAB separated list instead.
$ python -c <exampledata "import sys;print(''.join([ line.replace(')',' ').replace(' ','\t') for line in sys.stdin]) )" 
    105 John/M  Doe **Q 1   +**
    106 Jane/M  Doe **M 1   +**
    107 Rahman/Mujib    **M 1   +**
    108 Rahman/MOHAMMAD AZAD    **J 0**
    109 Ahmed/Zafar T   **1 +**
    110 Shah/Zaman  L   **1 +**
    111 RAHMAN/BHIMUL   **J 0**
    112 RASUL/SHEIK Z   **1 +**
    113 RHAMAN/ZIAUR    Q   **1 +**
    114 RUHI/RAWZI  ISLAM   Q   **0 +**
    115 SABUZ/RAQIB ISLAM   R   **2 +**

Yet another variant, pick out two columns:
$ python -c <exampledata "import sys;print('\n'.join([ '\t'.join(line.replace(')',' ').split(' ')[1:3]) for line in sys.stdin]) )" 
105 John/M
106 Jane/M
107 Rahman/Mujib
108 Rahman/MOHAMMAD
109 Ahmed/Zafar
110 Shah/Zaman
111 RAHMAN/BHIMUL
112 RASUL/SHEIK
113 RHAMAN/ZIAUR
114 RUHI/RAWZI
115 SABUZ/RAQIB

